# How to draw meshgrid or 2D quadtree (C , OpenCV)

Tags: c++, grid, draw, point, quadtree

may i know how to draw meshgrid or 2D quadtree (C++, OpenCV)? I just need to have defined points at each point of intersection within the quadtree for feedbacks or output, over an affected area. so the output should be able to tell me the maximum extent of points, for any shape.

Is it possible to do it?

Thx!